# Use \n in Python as a normal string

Tags: python

I am making a string calculator using numbers. For example:
*154 + 246 = 154246*

So the user will enter an input of a group of numbers, to separate the numbers using `\n`. As you know, `\n` is used to make a new line, but I need to use at as any normal string. I need to separate the numbers using `\n` into a list.

Code:

```py
num_list = []
# this function will add a number to the list
def ask_num():
    # ask for a number (we will make it a string so we can add comma and /n)
    num = input("Enter numbers: ")

    
# run the function for asking numbers
ask_num()
```

Comment: `/n` is not used for a new line. `\n` is.

Comment: Are you trying to append strings together, or make a calculator that takes strings as input? Your example of `154 + 256 = 154256` looks like just appending?

Comment: The elements in the list will not be separated by anything unless you put the list in a string and then work on the string later on.

Comment: Yes, putting them beside each other *in order*

Comment: Oh okay. thanks! everyone! **thx**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
r"\n"
```

or

```
"\\n"
```

Comment: Right, you can use the prefix r to prevent escape sequences to be executed. +1

Comment: The `r"\n"` seems to work properly, IDK why rest solutions don't work, just leaves a \\ at the start of each num

Comment: Just for other people to understand:

Answer (score 5):

You can *escape* the `\n` using an other `\`.

```
>>> print("\\n")
\n
>>> print("\n")


>>> print("/n")
/n
```

---

In your case, you asked for `/n`, which is not used for a newline, so you can normally use it in a string.

Comment: I just sometimes confuse between the both!

Answer (score 1):

Successful solution:

```py
def ask_num():
    num_list = []
    # ask for a number (we will make it a string so we can add comma and /n)
    num = input("Enter numbers: ")
    # put the num in the list
    num_list.append(num)
    # seperate the numbers
    num_list = num.split(r"\n")
    # print the list
    print(num_list)
```